# how to implement the radiobuttons text for multiple answers?

Tags: android, textview, radio-button

Im new to android..

Im facing a problem in `Nextbutton` while displaying the next four option answers for question...

In my first time set text im getting the correct question and matched four option answers. What i needed is..

I have a `nextbutton` for displaying the next question and answers..When click on next button i can get the next question..

**And at the same i need to get next four options from the arraylist....
How to implement this?** Any help would be appreciated...Thanks a lot in advance..

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
      ques1=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(ques1));
            //  j=0;
            TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
            txtque.setText(ques1.get(j));
            answ1=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(answ1));
            btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get(0));
            btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get(1));
            btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get(2));
            btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get(3));
        Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn);

        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){  

          j++;
          TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
          txtque.setText(ques1.get(j));         
         }
       });
}
```

How can i implement the radiobutton text in onClick event of Nextbutton?

Comment: @vikalp patel how to implement this? any help

Comment: @ram kiran how implement this help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    nextbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            j++;// j is your ques1 Array index number
            txtque.setText(ques1.get(j));
                            k++;  // k is your answ1 Array index number
            btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+0));
            btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+1));
            btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+2));
            btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+3));

        }
    });
```

Comment: no, i didnt get the answer, its showing first four options alone for all questions...and "i" is my index num of ques1 arrayList

Comment: Im having two arrays one is for questions and other one is for answers. so question array index is "i" and answer array index is "k"..  but first question and first four option im getting correctly. when i click on next im getting problem in radio buttons...im not getting the next four options... how to implement this...

Answer (score 0):

You can use two ArrayLists, first for all questions and second for four options of each question, something like this..

```
ArrayList<String> allQue = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> options = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put("optionFirst","your option");
map.put("optionSecond","your option");
map.put("optionThird","your option");
map.put("optionFourth","your option");

options.add(map);
```

In this way put all of your answers

Then on OnClick of nextButton do

```
txtque.setText(allQur.get(j).toString());
```

and for options...

```
 btn_practice1.setText(options.get(j).get("optionFirst").toString());
 btn_practice2.setText(options.get(j).get("optionSecond").toString());
 btn_practice3.setText(options.get(j).get("optionThird").toString());
 btn_practice4.setText(options.get(j).get("optionFour").toString());
```

Comment: I have separate array for all questions(4 questions) in ques1 and separate array for all answers(16 options each question 4 options) in answ1..